# Scala Jackson Serialization add computed field to serialized case class

Tags: json, scala, serialization, jackson

I have a scala case class:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int) {
    def isMillenial: Boolean = age <= someConstantMillenialThreshold
}
```

This serializes into the following json (using the ScalaJsonFactory object mapper to serialize):

```
{
    name: "foo",
    age: 42
}
```

However I want it to be serialized as follows:

```
{
    name: "foo",
    age: 42,
    isMillenial: true
}
```

Is there any way of doing this in a simple way, preferably by using some Jackson annotation or something similar? Basically looking for any solution which doesn't involve changing the `case class Person` or creating new objects

Answer (score 0):

Done! Looks like we can do this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
case class Person(name: String, age: Int) {
    @JsonProperty("isMillenial") def isMillenial: Boolean = age <= someConstantMillenialThreshold
}
```